# Return to Main Image

Tags: javascript, image

So I have a little javascript code that swaps my main image on hover of the thumbnails that works perfectly well! is their a way to return to main on hover out I am sure there is a little if statement but i cannot figure it out!

```
<div class="product"><img id="main" src="mainImage.jpg" width="550"/></div>
<div class="products">
 <img src="img.jpg" width="200"/>
 <img src="img1.jpg" width="200"/>
 <img src="img2.jpg" width="200"/>
</div>
```

and the javascript is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.products img').mouseover(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main').attr('src', url);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    var def_url =  $('#main').attr('src');
    $('.products img').hover(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#main').attr('src', url);
    }, function() {
       $('#main').attr('src', def_url);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$('.products img').mouseover(function() {
//do some action...
},function (){
//undo the action..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `hover().` when you move mouse out of it , it restores original state and hovered gives you the required functionality.

**So, it is a combination of two functions mouserover() and mouseout()**

**hope this helps..**

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in two ways:

1) use jQuery `hover` [hover documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(selector).hover(
    function(){ alert("Hover in"); },
    function(){ alert("Hover out); }
 );
```

2) use `<div>` with background image and change it on hover with css

```
#selector{
    background: url('image1.png');
}

#selector:hover{
    background: url('image2.png');
}
```